# how to get proper spacing in php output from the shell?

Tags: php

When I am trying to show some output of a command fired to shell with `system()` in php, the output is not showing the proper spacing. 
i used the command

```
system("$command");
```

but its not getting porpoer spacing, the output is just getting messed up in spacing!

Any solution ?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far, including the output & expected output

Comment: I wonder how "messed up spacing" looks like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the command in a html `<pre>` tag.

```
<pre><?php system("$command");?></pre>
```

Comment: Perfect. You should validate my answer in order to close the subject. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to retain spaces from output of shell. You have to replace  spaces with  non breaking space so your spaces are retained.

```
 $val = shell_exec ("$command");
 $correctedspace = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $val);
 echo $correctedspace
```